# Can you see Putin in Duomo di Milano?

Tags: europe, italy, factoids, milan

My friend visited Duomo in Milan, where their tour guide told them that a large number of statues and figures appears on Duomo. She asked which modern people appear there?

Tour guide replied that people who have made a *significant contribution* appear there, e.g. *Vladimir Putin*.

Is this true?

I couldn't find any online resource to back this up and the tour guide told them about Putin verbally, they didn't actually see it there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Milan Cathedral does not include a statue of Vladimir Putin.

I haven't been able to find any complete list of all statues on the building (there are, after all, literally thousands of them). But putting "putin statue milan cathedral", "milan duomo putin", and several other similar terms into my preferred search engine provided absolutely no results (not even from unrealiable-looking websites) to back up the idea that there's any statue or other representation of Putin.

The explanation that he's allegedly depicted as he made a "significant contribution" is implausible. Construction started in the 1300s and was completed in 1965. In 1965 Vladimir Putin turned 13 years old. Displays of religious belief were, shall we say, "heavily discouraged" in the Soviet Union. It's difficult to imagine how or why he would have made a significant contribution to a Roman Catholic cathedral in Milan (he is not a Catholic, like the vast majority of Christians in Russia he is a member of the Russian Orthodox church).

Of course a contribution could also be made later on to upkeep, not just construction. "Complete" is a loose term, there are apparently some marble blocks not yet carved into statues. But any contribution "significant" enough that they would *carve a statue of the donor as part of the cathedral* is surely a mind-bogglingly large sum. For a man with no obvious links to Milan and who belongs to an entirely different branch of Christianity to make such a contribution would be extremely difficult to explain. For him to somehow avoid any publicity from it despite his extremely public position, even more so.

All in all, the idea is absurd enough - and Putin a well-known enough public figure - that I consider the absence of evidence to be **extremely** compelling evidence of absence.

Comment: I doubt that construction having finished in 1965 implies that no statutes have been installed since then.

Comment: @phoog I was actually editing to address that as you wrote.

Comment: With an active restoration and cleaning process (e.g. with the 5-year 2002 project to restore the marbles) and an active architect of the cathedral, as well as the marble being still fetched through the river from another vicinity of Italy, I would easily imagine someone's figure getting shape in the Duomo today, so I agree with @phoog. However I understand how oxymoron it would be for Putin to make a massive donation to Duomo, since as an Orthodox he could do it for Hagia Sophia in Constantinoupolis (where politics wouldn't allow him to now that I think of it).. To conclude I agree with you!

Comment: Actually the Duomo is mantained and "upgraded" since 1387 from the ["Veneranda fabbrica del Duomo"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veneranda_Fabbrica_del_Duomo_di_Milano) and they replace and also add statues, so in theory there could be a Putin statue...but no, he hasn't deserved it until now. Different story about the "adopt a statue" and "get your spire" foundraising projects [official link](https://www.duomomilano.it/en/infopage/adopt-a-statue/126/) by the duomo for recover removed statues or restoration. You can put your name in a public list, but not buy a space in the Duomo.